# Running bat file from SQL server job

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, sql-server-agent

I have a bat file. If I run it, it does everything it's supposed to do.

Now I want to run that bat file from SQL server job.
[image]

RunProg.bat consists of this:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.2\bin\RScript.exe" "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.2\bin\QA_Check.R"
```

Error when I run job is this:
[image]

I think problem is in access. How can I fix it?

Users on my machine:
[image]

Comment: The batch job resides on  your desktop? Or on the SQL Server? You should put it on the SQL Server itself in a folder that is accessible to the SQL Server Agent Service Account, which probably does not have access to your User folder.

Comment: Also, the scripts in the batch job should be put on the SQL Server as well.

Comment: `Access is Denied`... aka, the user your SQL server is running under does not have permissions to execute your batch file.

Comment: @WEI_DBA , SQL server is running on local machine. How do I know to which files SQL Server Agent Service Account have access to?

Comment: @MatthewWhited , which permission should I give to user ?

Comment: If the Service Account is a local admin, it should have access. Go to Local Users / Groups and see what permissions it has. Usually, only admins and yourself will have access to your personal folders (Users/Desktop/etc)

Comment: SQL should not be running as local admin.  It should be network service by default.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-windows-service-accounts-and-permissions

Comment: A better plan would be to move the batch file to somewhere that SQL has access.  You better still creating a custom user account for SQL to run under and configure it with a user profile and locate the batch file there.

Comment: @MatthewWhited , how do I know to which folders SQL has access to?

Comment: it will have access to the folders it is installed under... but again, create a new folder and grant execute permissions to network service to that folder.  Check the link I provided above.

Comment: @WEI_DBA , I've updated post with user groups, which one should I change and to what? My local instance is SHOW

Comment: @MatthewWhited , that is too advanced topic, which will take days to understand. I run on SQL Server 2016 instance. Can someone say something like copy this file there, change this and that will run

Comment: Go into the Users and see what permissions the SQL Server Agent Service Account has. Then give it Administrator and all should work.

Comment: DO NOT give `NETWORK SERVICE` admin access.

Comment: @WEI_DBA ,  I went into Logins -> right click NTService/SQLAgent$SHOW  properties -> Server Roles (public & sysadmin were selected) -> I've enabled all others too (bulkadmin, dbcreator,diskadmin, processadmin, securityadmin, serveradmin,setupadmin).  But job still fails with same error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Having a similar issue, what worked for me was to change the location of the .bat file to a folder location where the SQL agent would run it. So, instead of "C:\Users\MyUser\BatFolder\my.bat", I moved it to "D:\BatFolder\my.bat" where the Agent had access.